# Buttons are resizing in simulator?

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5

Can someone tell me why these buttons are resizing themselves in the iPad simulator?
This is what they look like in the .xib builder

[image]

But when running the simulator they end up looking like this:

[image]

I have "unchecked" Autoresize subviews in both the VIEW, and each BUTTON. Still, they resize?

Comment: Have you checked the autosizing settings in the size inspector when you view your xib in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 2, 3, 4 & 7 button are not positioning perfectly. As it looking all buttons are same in size so replace these 4 button image with a good one (eg. 1) and run it again. Now observed the problem still there or not. If not solve then just delete these 4 buttons and try with complete new. If still it remain same then positioning the buttons programmatically with size. Hope it helps you.